# In override equal method, this keyword is not pass as a parameter while comparing the attributes?

Tags: java, equals

I have seen lots of example of overriding equals method. But in every example, while fields comparison, why we don't pass parameter like this.firstName in `Objects.equals(firstName, person.firstName)`, but just pass `firstName`

Why we don't write like `Objects.equals(this.firstName, person.firstName)`

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // self check
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    // null check
    if (o == null)
        return false;
    // type check and cast
    if (getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;
    Person person = (Person) o;
    // field comparison
    return Objects.equals(firstName, person.firstName)
            && Objects.equals(lastName, person.lastName);
}
```

Comment: There is no other symbol called `firstName` in scope, so there is no ambiguity. You could use `this.firstName`, if you feel it is clearer.

Comment: @AndyTurner, thanks for pointing out